# MySQL Database stores question marks instead of special characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, special-characters, utf8mb4

I am trying to displaying VERY Special Characters (like    ) inside of my website, and storing it into my database.
When I write special characters like those, they get once displayed, but when I reload the page and the server gets the string from the Database, it gets displayed as "??????? ?????? ?????? ??????"
I tried to do a lot of things to fix this, but none of them worked.
This isn't a visualization problem, because the header is set right:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

What I did try to do:

- Setting the server's default charset to utf8.
- Setting the database/table/column collapse and charset to utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- Changing the connect string to:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$db->query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4");

mb_language('uni'); 

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$db->query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");

$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

But nothing of this things worked.
As an addition, I tried (Just for debugging) to change a string in the text field of the database to    , and I got an error:

> Warning: #1300 Invalid utf8 character string: 'F09D91'
>
> Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x91\xBB\xF0\x9D...' for column 'text' at row 1

I tried really every solution I found here and outsite, but nothing worked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about the file's encoding itself?

Comment: What files should I check exactly?

Comment: All of them. If you don't know how to check a file's encoding, get a code editor and see what it says under "encoding".

Comment: I use Notepad++ to  edit them, so I'm ok.
The files' encoding is UTF-8 Without BOM.

Comment: Consult the following on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/ and see if you can use a different encoding method. Plus, try putting all the code following `$db->query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4");` before that line. Also try a different file encoding. I've had to do that myself before, oddly enough. It could also be the server's default encoding that may be overriding something, somewhere; I've had that problem before also.

Comment: Addendum to the above. If you're querying somewhere, as in doing a SELECT, UPDATE or INSERT, then it is important that the encoding codes are placed before the query, should that be the case.

Comment: I love you so much.
That did the trick!
Thanks man!

Comment: You're quite welcome and I'm glad to hear it. I'll post my comment as an answer to a certain extent, if you wish to accept it and mark the question as solved.

Comment: Of course, I was waiting for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As discussed in comments.*

In many cases, you need to place all of the code following
`$db->query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4");` **before** that line.

Also using a different file encoding could also help.

I've had to do that myself before, oddly enough. It could also be the server's default encoding that may be overriding something, somewhere; I've had that problem before also.

Plus, if you're querying somewhere, as in doing a SELECT, UPDATE or INSERT, then it is **important** that the encoding codes are placed before the query, should that be the case.

Comment: Thanks man, this did the trick.
U saved me from insomnia and time-wast.

Comment: @SimoneVenturas You're most welcome Simone and I know "that" feeling all too well, *cheers*

Comment: $db->query("SET character_set_results=utf8mb4"); before that line. 
"that line"? which line?

Comment: I have a laravel project where i need to make changes in database config file and set 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' also the column where you are storing special character should have collation 'utf8_unicode_ci' or 'utf16_unicode_ci'